# Recovering data from Mac OS X encrypted SSD with broken MBR

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, disk-encryption, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

On my Mac, running on Mawericks OSX, I had whole encrypted SSD (240 Gb). By mistake (instead of external, and same size! HDD plugged in), I've chosen wrong disk (my SSD) for Linux installation. So on my SSD, after deleting "unknown" disk, I have made 3 partitions: 5Gb-ext4, 1Gb-linux-temp and rest ~234Gb-ntfs. More over, I have done Linux installation on 5Gb partition.

I've tried some file recovery tools, but all it found, were some ancient pieces of few old files. I do understand none of such tools will help, as all data on it is (was) encrypted.

**My question: do I still have any chances recovering at least something from it?**

I did browse and red hours on this topic, but so far - I've found nothing promising. Will you please suggest me what could I do in such case? And just a thought: any chances to recover some bits of data if: **I'd re-format my SSD and encrypt it again using same encryption key (password) - will then, data-recovery tools see anything**?

Comment: So you deleted the partitions, but did your format them? Then you wrote information over where the (encrypted) data was (or could have been)? And then you've tried tools to recover the data to no avail? Unless you want to spend the money sending it out to a professional service, I'd say no there's no chance.

Comment: Your data was encrypted.  You also in the process deleted your only method of encrypting your files.  Data recovery won't be possible in a case like this.  The process of installing OS X will overwrite some of your data.

Comment: I'm not sure how _quick-format_ acts (is not the _low-level-format_), but YES - all 3 partitions were set for a new format and changes were applied. The new data was written only in to ext4 (5Gb) partition. 1 Gb Linux-Swap partition and rest, 230 Gb NTFS partition were unwritten. Data recovering tools I've tried (DiskDrill / DataResque / EaseUS) can not see a thing. Does it makes sense **making an image file of whole SDD** - will this could be used in future trying to recover anything from it?

Comment: _The process of installing OS X will overwrite some of your data._ - I do agree on loosing **some** of data, but my curiosity is very technical - if newly installed same OS, on a same SSD and used **same encryption key** as previously - will make DataRecovery tools see previous things which were encrypted? This might be nonsense - I'm not sure. Unless there's better way of _last chance_.

Comment: If the repartition didn't kill your chances, the nix install almost certainly did. This is why we have *backups*.

Comment: So _almost_ or _certainly_? For now is just a technical question which in my understanding should have a rational explanation. All I've got for now, is whole SSD's **image file** (after it got unuseful). From my understanding - it is just 240Gb of informational mess. Is there any software, which using a original pass-code and knowing previous disk format (MacOS Journaled Encrypted) which would try to _see_ through this mess the real data? Any thoughts? Technically: if I know the encryption type and a key, can I _extract_ from a piece of _mess_ real data? Should be possible - isn't it?